# Prevent IIS 7.5 from displaying default error pages using the web.config

Tags: c#, web-applications, webforms, iis-7.5

I am trying to add custom error pages to my web application.  So far I have added this to my web.config file under the  element:

```
<customErrors mode="On" >
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx"/>
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/500.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

This works fine for errors that .NET touches for example a url that contains the .aspx extension.  However I also want custom errors to display for a url such as www.example.com/dasda

Currently when I request a page such as the above IIS 7.5 displays it's own error message.  I have added this under the  element:

```
<httpErrors >
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="~/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"  />
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="500" path="~/500.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

I thought that this would make IIS display a custom error page instead of it's default ones but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I am aware that I can set a custom error page in IIS itself but an ideal solution for my situation would be to have this configurable in the web.config.

I have tried adding this into my custom error pages on the Page_Load event as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166523/asp-net-application-hosted-on-iis7-that-is-ignoring-custom-errors-and-falls-back) :

```
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

However it did not stop the default IIS page from showing in place of my custom error page.  I have also tried what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888743/httperror-will-not-show-custom-error-pages):

```
<httpErrors >
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode='-1' />
    <error statusCode="404" path="~/404.aspx" prefixLanguageFilePath='' responseMode="Redirect"  />
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode='-1' />
    <error statusCode="500" path="~/500.aspx" prefixLanguageFilePath='' responseMode="Redirect" />
  </httpErrors>
```

But this has also not worked.

So is there a way to prevent IIS from displaying default error pages by configuring settings in the web.config file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem I was encountering was that by default  has an attribute errorMode with the following options: DetailedLocalOnly, Custom or Detailed.

If the errorMode attribute is left unspecified as I was doing then it defaults to DetailedLocalOnly ([ref](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors)). Which means I would not have seen the custom error that was displayed.

The configuration settings that worked were:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode='-1' />
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode='-1' />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/404.aspx" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL"  />
    <error statusCode="500" path="/500.aspx" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  </httpErrors>
```

The errorMode="Custom" is handy to test the custom pages are working correctly but is probably more handy when left omitted or set explicitly to errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks Aesir for posting this. I was able to fix a same problem with your example.

Comment: Thanks for discovering the errorMode flag; the lack of effect was annoying the heck out of me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to force IIS to use the CustomErrorModule for any resource requested by the user.
Try to add the below to your web config

```
 <modules>
      <add name="CustomErrorModule" type="customErrorModule" preCondition="" />
 </modules>
```

Have also a look at the below link

https://serverfault.com/questions/53712/in-iis-7-how-do-i-set-up-a-default-error-document-for-any-error

Comment: Thanks, what part of the web.config should this be added to?  I tried putting it in the httpModules and the modules section but neither worked.

Comment: Thank you the update however it still didn't work.  I have managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you have a JSON response coming from your server, by setting `existingResponse="PassThrough"`, you instruct IIS to pass through the HTTP error response without handling it. This allows your server's JSON response to be sent to the client directly.

```xml
</system.webServer>   
    <!-- Avoid showing the default IIS error pages and display JSON response -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```