# Why does my 404 redirect not work in my web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-errors

In my application I have a custom error for catching all unexpected errors and a 404 for when a user tries to go to a page that does not exist. The issue is, in production I can navigate successfully to an error page either by typing the path to the url in the browser window or by misuse of application but I cannot do the same with the 404. Here is my setup.[image]

Comment: try `<clear />` all current rules before specifying new.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov a clear inside of custom errors results in an error 500, this also occurs if I place it before custom errors

Comment: Okay, my bad, messed with `httpErrors`.

Comment: where does it not work? on your desktop running IISExpress?  On a deployed Server instance running IIS somewhere?

Comment: It does not work in production on an IIS Server IIS 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Error/NotFound` will work instead of `~/Error/NotFound` and custom errors should be enabled (depending on where you are making requests from):

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error/NotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

And also set `httpErrors`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough">
        <clear />
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Beware that `clear` will remove static files for all errors. So consider to unlock an set `defaultPath` of `httpErrors`.

Comment: I tried this and it still does not work. It generates the same as the error shown above

Comment: Looks like it is because 404 is handled by IIS, not ASP.NET. Try also override `httpErrors`.

Comment: @Skullomania, I have updated my answer, hope it will help. That's how it was done on one of my previous projects.

Comment: I have added your updated suggestion to my webconfig in place of my custom errors as well as adding it below system.web with the same result. I have no clue what is going on. I can navigate to `notfound` the page in my local project but not in production

Comment: It replaces default IIS error pages. Can it be that this section is disabled on production somehow? You navigate to not found on local after changing `httpErrors` or you could do it from start?

Comment: Have a look at this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888743/httperror-will-not-show-custom-error-pages

Comment: I did what it suggested and I am still having the same result. I am very close to scrapping this web.config and rewriting it from scratch just to see what the issue is.

Comment: Although this makes no sense, yesterday I used On instead of RemoteOnly and it started working. I am not sure why it started working because I tried that before as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay, good to know. It might be because the server and client was on the same machine.

Comment: It worked for me like: `existingResponse="Replace"` The full code : `<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <clear />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>`

Answer (score 3):

Possibly include errorMode as "Custom" and responseMode as "File" if you are trying to redirect to a custom error file as shown below.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="FileNotFound.html" responseMode="File"/>
  </httpErrors>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thank-you for contributing. Feel free to edit your answer at a later stage if you would like to expand on it or include some more detail that you might have left out.